# Using AWK to count multiple patterns in a file

Tags: parsing, logging, awk

I tried using awk to parse IP and occurrences from a log file, I wanted the output to be something like this:

```
IP1 occurences
IP2 ocurrences
```

The log I have is something like

```
2023-03-30 07:14:32.494 INFO  [asda/1737.140291506677312] cmd <IP> has been allocated
```

I tried with the following code

```
awk '/100.64./{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/100.64./){a[$i]++} {for (x in a) print x,a[x]}}'
```

but I got a mixed list with non unique IPs and a lot of different counts. What´s wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance,

Example:

```
2023-03-30 10:39:31.214 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291531855424] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.147.36 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:31.598 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291506677312] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.146.13 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:31.745 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291523462720] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.146.4 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:32.396 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291515070016] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.147.17 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:32.466 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291531855424] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.144.122 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:33.079 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291506677312] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.144.161 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:33.220 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291523462720] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.144.77 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:33.407 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291515070016] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.147.66 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:33.427 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291531855424] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.149.201 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:33.839 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291506677312] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.146.45 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:34.530 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291523462720] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.144.47 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:35.098 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291515070016] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.144.30 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:35.249 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291531855424] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.147.54 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
2023-03-30 10:39:36.081 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.140291506677312] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1<REDACTED>: lease 100.64.144.77 has been allocated for 43200 seconds
```

Result:

```
100.64.147.36 1
100.64.147.36 1
100.64.146.13 1
100.64.147.36 1
100.64.146.13 1
100.64.146.4 1
100.64.147.36 1
...
...
...
100.64.147.36 1
100.64.144.30 1
100.64.144.161 1
100.64.147.66 1
100.64.146.13 1
100.64.149.201 1
100.64.146.4 1
100.64.144.47 1
100.64.146.45 1
100.64.144.122 1
100.64.144.77 2
100.64.147.17 1
```

Expected Result:

```
100.64.144.122 1
100.64.144.161 1
100.64.144.30 1
100.64.144.47 1
100.64.144.77 2
100.64.146.13 1
100.64.146.4 1
100.64.146.45 1
100.64.147.17 1
100.64.147.36 1
100.64.147.54 1
100.64.147.66 1
100.64.149.201 1
```

Comment: will ***all*** lines in the file have the same exact number of space-delimited fields as shown in the provided sample? if the the file can contain differently formatted lines then please update the sample input to include a more representative set of lines from the log file; also of key importance ... will ***all*** lines contain exactly one IP address in the 8th space-delimited field (eg, could a line have multiple IP addresses that need to be counted? could a line have no IP addresses?)?

Comment: Sadly nope, not all the time the IP is in the same "column" but yes, only one ip per line.

Comment: please update the question with a more representable set of data from the log file ... we need to see the different line formats; also, please verify if *any* lines could exist that do *not* contain an IP address

Comment: Regarding [Sadly nope, not all the time the IP is in the same "column"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75888699/using-awk-to-count-multiple-patterns-in-a-file#comment133859224_75888699) - if the IP address isn't always in the same place in your real data then don't show it always in the same place in the example you provide to demonstrate your problem and for us to test a potential solution with. Make sure the sample input/output you provide is truly representative of your real data so you don't get solutions to a problem other than the one you actually have

Comment: Also, your code is specifically testing for `100.64.` but all of your IP addresses start with that so there's no point testing for it. If that's NOT representative of reality and your real input has different IP addresses that you do not want counted, then include those cases in the example you provide for us too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions:

- we want to count all IP addresses regardless of the format of the line
- not all lines in the log file contain an IP address
- no lines have more than one IP address

For the proposed code the format of the file doesn't matter so for demo purposes I'm using a reduced/modified data set:

```
$ cat ip.log
2023-03-30 10:39:31.214 INFO  [dhcp4] DLA [ht=1<RED>: lease 100.64.147.36 allocated
2023-03-30 10:39:31.598 INFO  [dhcp4] DLA [ht=1<RED>: lease 100.64.146.13 allocated
2023-03-30 10:39:31.745 INFO  [dhcp4] DLA [ht=1<RED>: lease 100.64.146.4 allocated
2023-03-30 10:39:32.396 INFO  [dhcp4] DLA [ht=1<RED RELEASE>: release 100.64.147.36 deallocated
2023-03-30 10:39:32.466 INFO  [dhcp4] DLA [ht=1<RED NOTHING TO SEE>: nothing to see here
2023-03-30 10:39:33.079 ERROR  [dhcp4] DLA [ht=1<RED ERROR>: failed 100.64.144.161
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
    { if ( match($0,/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/) )  # if we find a 4-tuple string (aka ip address) ...
         counts[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++                             # use the ip as an array index and increment the count stored in the array
    }
END { for (ip in counts) print ip,counts[ip] }                           # loop through array entries and print ip address and count
' ip.log
```

This generates:

```
100.64.147.36 2
100.64.144.161 1
100.64.146.13 1
100.64.146.4 1
```

**NOTES:**

- if OP needs the output sorted one (easy) solution would be to pipe this output to the desired `sort` command
- this will also match on non-ip strings like `999.999.999.999`; if this is a concern the regex could be modified to reduce these types of invalid matches
- as coded this will not match on ipv6 addresses

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '{cnt[$8]++} END{for (i in cnt) print i, cnt[i]}' file
100.64.147.54 1
100.64.147.36 1
100.64.144.30 1
100.64.144.161 1
100.64.147.66 1
100.64.146.13 1
100.64.149.201 1
100.64.146.4 1
100.64.144.47 1
100.64.146.45 1
100.64.144.122 1
100.64.144.77 2
100.64.147.17 1
```

If your input did contain IP addresses that don't start with `100.64.` and you wanted only counts of the `100.64.*` ones then it'd be:

```
awk '$8 ~ /^100\.64\./{cnt[$8]++} END{for (i in cnt) print i, cnt[i]}' file
```

The main problems with your code:

```
awk '/100.64./{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/100.64./){a[$i]++} {for (x in a) print x,a[x]}}'
```

are:

1. You're looping through every field in the line looking for matches to `$i~/100.64./` when you only want to match on field 8 given the example you provided, and
2. The `.`s in `100.64.` aren't escaped with `\` and so each `.` will match any character so that'd match in "[kea-dhcp4.leases/1737.**100**2**64**506677312]" or similar, and
3. You don't anchor your regexp at the front with `^` so `100.64.` would match `10.100.64.17` or similar, and
4. You're printing the array contents every time you read a line of input instead of once in an `END` section after all input has been read.

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands:

```
grep -Po 'lease\s+\K\S+' infile | sort | uniq -c | perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F[1, 0]; '
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

`sort` : sort the output of `grep` (the IP addresses), which is needed for `uniq`.
`uniq -c` : count the occurrences of the sorted IP addresses.
`perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F[1, 0];`  : reverse the order of the fields: print the IP, then the number of occurrences.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**See also:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: `| awk '$0 = $2 "\t" $1'` seems a more direct way to reorder

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` solution. Which uses `FPAT` variable of GNU `awk` where we are setting the regex to get only matched values as per requirement.

```
awk -v FPAT='lease ([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3} ' '
{
  gsub(/^lease | $/,"",$1)
  arr[$1]++
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i,arr[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cut -d" " -f9 file|sort|uniq -c|awk '$0=$2" "$1'
100.64.144.122 1
100.64.144.161 1
100.64.144.30 1
100.64.144.47 1
100.64.144.77 2
100.64.146.13 1
100.64.146.4 1
100.64.146.45 1
100.64.147.17 1
100.64.147.36 1
100.64.147.54 1
100.64.147.66 1
100.64.149.201 1
```

looking for `100.64...`

```
$ grep -Eo "100\.64\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}" file|sort|uniq -c|awk '$0=$2" "$1'
```